# AWS CLI - how to see EC2 System Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

How to see System Logs of an EC2 instance (I have instance id) by using AWS CLI (from terminal) of my laptop? (same as I can see them via AWS Web console 'System logs')
I would like to see all major events that are happening for some EC2 instance (reboot, start, stop, what was loaded at a high level etc.)

Answer (score 6):

`get-console-output` API of AWS CLI will fetch you the required output.

Here is the official documentation reference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/get-console-output.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to see it as a line-by-line and not all scrambled into 1 line output? (I am guessing some parsing can be done on my side but wanted to check if there is command that does that already) and also - how can I see real TIMESTAMPS? (instead of [   29.513573])

Comment: Add `--output text` to get the log line by line.

Answer (score 3):

[aws ec2 get-console-output --instance-id i-1234567890abcdef0](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html#instance-console-console-output)

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to see it as a line-by-line and not all scrambled into 1 line output? (I am guessing some parsing can be done on my side but wanted to check if there is command that does that already) and also - how can I see real TIMESTAMPS? (instead of [   29.513573])